# How to get Autocomplete results for places using Google Places API for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, autocomplete, google-api

I am trying to display autocomplete results using Google Places API for iOS, I might be missing something but here is my code for the task:

```
- (void)placeAutocomplete {

    GMSVisibleRegion visibleRegion = mapView_.projection.visibleRegion;
    //GMSCoordinateBounds *bounds = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc] initWithCoordinate:visibleRegion.farLeft
                                                                    //   coordinate:visibleRegion.nearRight];
    GMSAutocompleteFilter *filter = [[GMSAutocompleteFilter alloc] init];
    filter.type = kGMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilterGeocode;
    GMSPlacesClient *placesClient;
        [placesClient autocompleteQuery:@"indira nagar"
                              bounds:nil
                              filter:filter
                            callback:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
                                if (error != nil) {
                                    NSLog(@"Autocomplete error %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                                    return;
                                }

                                for (GMSAutocompletePrediction* result in results) {
                                    NSLog(@"Result '%@' with placeID %@", result.attributedFullText.string, result.placeID);
                                }
                            }];
}
```

I've added the pods(`pod 'GoogleMaps'`), I even got the map But when i try autocomplete all I am getting is (in the log)`"Google Maps SDK for iOS version: 1.10.17867.0"` can any one help understand how it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the issue of my api key so i had to change(create a new one) to resolve this issue